# Inserting last data object into first table row - HTML

Tags: html, html-table, createelement

The following `data`:

```
[
  { address: '101 Main Street', date_created: '2022/11/01', price: '£100,000' },
  { address: '101 Main Street', date_created: '2022/10/27', price: '£200,000' },
  { address: '101 Main Street', date_created: '2022/10/20', price: '300,000' },
];
```

is passed to my `createTable` function:

```
function createTable({ data, propertyId }) {
  const table = createElement({
    tag: 'table',
    id: `p-${propertyId}`,
    border: '1',
  });

  const tableHeader = createElement({
    tag: 'caption',
    innerText: 'Table title',
  });

  const tableBody = createElement({
    tag: 'tbody',
  });

  data.forEach((item) => {
    const row = createElement({
      tag: 'tr',
    });

    const date = createElement({
      tag: 'td',
      innerHTML: item.date_created,
    });

    const price = createElement({
      tag: 'td',
      innerHTML: item.price,
    });

    row.append(date, price);
    tableBody.append(row);
  });

  table.append(tableHeader, tableBody);
  return table;
}
```

which creates the following output:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/11/01 | £100,000 |
| 2022/10/27 | £200,000 |
| 2022/10/20 | £300,000 |

This means that the first object is inserted into the first row and so on, however, I'd like to display the data in the opposite order. (Oldest data at the top, with newest at the bottom) - number of records can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function createTable({ data, propertyId }) {
    const table = createElement({
        tag: "table",
        id: `p-${propertyId}`,
        border: "1"
    });

    const tableHeader = createElement({
        tag: "caption",
        innerText: "Table title"
    });

    const tableBody = createElement({
        tag: "tbody"
    });

    // the change is here,  hope it helps
    data.sort((prev, current) => {
        const prevDate = prev["date_created"]
            .replace("/", "-")
            .replace("/", "-");
        const currentDate = current["date_created"]
            .replace("/", "-")
            .replace("/", "-");
        return new Date(prevDate) - new Date(currentDate);
    }).forEach(item => {
        const row = createElement({
            tag: "tr"
        });

        const date = createElement({
            tag: "td",
            innerHTML: item.date_created
        });

        const price = createElement({
            tag: "td",
            innerHTML: item.price
        });

        row.append(date, price);
        tableBody.append(row);
    });

    table.append(tableHeader, tableBody);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dante.- it works great for swapping two dates, but in the case whereby there are 3 are more, it still doesn't quite achieve what I'm looking for (oldest at top and newest at bottom)

Comment: What do you mean where there are 3 or more? Can you add an example of the sample data? Better you provide all types of sample data that you might be dealing with. Clears picture better. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I've updated the question to hopefully be a little more clear!

Comment: I think my answer solves your problem no matter how many dateset you have. Have you tried using my solution in your code ? Let me know if it worked.

Comment: My mistake - you are completely correct! thank you!!